# Jest error on upgrading to latest version - a worker process has failed to exit gracefully

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I recently updated my Jest package to the latest version from v24 and on running my unit tests, I am getting this at the end of test suite run:

```
A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. 
This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown.
Try running with --runInBand --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.
```

I added `--detectOpenHandles` with my test command and the messages goes in the next run. I am not sure how to take it as detectOpenHandles is intended for finding the open handles and not fixing it so how is the message not coming in next run and no other message to guide me on what could be the issue.

Has anyone came across similar behaviour? To add, I am on latest version of Jest i.e 27.2.0 now.

Comment: In my experience this usually indicates some asynchronous behaviour which continues to run after the test has completed. Do your tests contain asynchronous processes? Try running each test file separately to narrow down the problematic ones. If this error only appears when running the tests together do they contain something shared like a server or DB that more than one test file is accessing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I literally got huge number of tests and it won’t be an easy exercise to figure out which test file is causing it. I will have to do it eventually in case there is no other way but curious to know if jest could point me to it.

Comment: Have you set the `"testEnvironment": "jsdom"` in configuration. [Jest recently changed the default environment](https://jestjs.io/blog/2021/05/25/jest-27#flipping-defaults) from `jsdom` to `node` which breaks react apps.

Comment: Yes, i have already set "testEnvironment": "jsdom".

Comment: What do you mean by, "so how is the message not coming in next run"? Are you saying you're not getting any messages when running with the --detectOpenHandles flag?

Comment: `--detectOpenHandles` ignores async processes after the tests this is why you don't know whats causing it. An easy way to fix this is making every test async and waiting for each response or another option could be to teardown async processes properly such as db connection, api calls etc

Comment: Yeah, no warning or message on running with detectOpenHandles @JohnKim

Comment: @kmp 
You would think the expected behavior of '--detectOpenHandles' to... Detect open handles. At least that's what it's supposed to do, from the documentation, it's just that jest rarely ever does that properly and there's several issues on that already.

Comment: @JohnKim Yeah I know that :D thats why I said it ignores async processes, because its not working properly..at least when I last used it. I made everything async and awaited each response to avoid the issue (only in integration tests, but it should work in unit tests imo)

Answer (score 6):

From my research, the error occurs when :

- An async function did not finish
- A promise function did not finish
- A Websocket, Database, or anything else that has connect/disconnect methods did not disconnect before the end of the test

The error doesn't mention the fact that the tests will just hang most of the time even with `--detectOpenHandles` flag, which is probably the reason why you aren't seeing any useful debugging messages.

From the documentation :

> Attempt to collect and print open handles preventing Jest from exiting cleanly. Use this in cases where you need to use `--forceExit` in order for Jest to exit to potentially track down the reason. This implies -`-runInBand`, making tests run serially. Implemented using async_hooks, so it only works in Node 8 and newer. This option has a significant performance penalty and should only be used for debugging.`

As it says in the documentation, you could try running the tests using the `--detectOpenHandles` and the `--forceExit` flag. This would mean the tests would run serially and each test would force exit when a test doesn't complete due to improper teardown. Let me know if this works.

Comment: This gives some good information about finding the source of the problem but doesn't give a useable solution to solve it. `--forceExit` feels like a bandaid. There should be a way to prevent the problem in the first place.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Not sure what kind of solution that you would like, other than me attempting to fix the problem by contributing to Jest. The "problem" originates from OP's code, as having the symptoms I described would clearly indicate incorrect code. I provided a working workaround that has at least worked for me, and provided possible origins of the problem. The OP didn't provide anywhere near specific context to his particular issue. Sorry to say there is no general "fix everything" flag in Jest that can handle every kind of hanging function or improper teardown.

Comment: I'm not looking for a "fix everything flag". I think a solution would be to figure out how to close the open handles cleanly rather than just forcing the test process to exit.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My solution is literally that. The --forceExit flag allows you to check which tests forceExited, and figure out what problem there is in that specific test, from the list of possible problems that I listed in my solution. "Figure out how to close the open handles" is the OP's job, it's not up to Jest to code a working application for him. If he wants to know what is causing the open handle in the specific test after he tracks it down using my solution, he can create another question. However it's usually an easy fix, the hard part is figuring out which test is the problem.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. I thought you were suggesting `--forceExit` as a final solution. My mistake.